# Downloader for Evernote data

Tags: download-manager, evernote

I have a lot of pages stored in Evernote.

I'd like to be able to download them for offline non-Evernote backup (as HTML pages).

Is there a software that would let me do that?

- Platform: Windows. Windows 10+ desired.
- Cost: Gratis preferred.
- License: don't care

Comment: You just want to export all of your notes as individual .html files? What about the attachments that may be present?

Comment: @Raystafarian - no preference. If attachments are doable it's a plus but not required

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, but on my version - `W7 5.8.3.6507` I can go to *File - Export - Multiple web pages (.html)* - does yours not have that? Or is it not what you want?

Comment: @Raystafarian - I have not been aware of that feature as I almost exclusively used web and Android stuff. Is that available on non-pro version? If so, please add as an answer.

Comment: It should be, I'm not on pro anymore and it's still there.

Comment: The export option is available in the desktop app which can be downloaded from the official site. If you have found any other downloader, please let me know.